# Do we have to use the function value in wrapped function of a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, python-decorators

```
def div2(mult):
    def display():

        print(f"we are doing a check of multiples if div by 2")
        if mult%2==0:
            return f"{mult} is divisible"
    return display

@div2
def multi(n):
    return n*n*n

print(multi(5))
```

In a video i learnt that we need not pass an argument for the wrapped function(display in this e.g), the main function's argument(`div2` in this case) will be used in the wrapped function.
When i tried the same for the above code i got a `TypeError` that `display()` needs a parameter.

Confused now that in this case should all my 3 functions should have the parameters as below:
`div2()` -> `multi()` function itself as parameter
`display()` -> a parameter to display the value of function `multi()`
`multi()` -> a parameter to do the math

Note: When I made `display()` take a parameter, the code worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that `display` doesn't take an argument; it's that you use it as if it does. Remember that decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar for

```
def multi(n):
    return n*n*n

multi = div2(multi)
```

The result of `div2` isn't required to preserve the signature of `div2`'s argument, though you have to know if it does or not before you can *use* that result.

The argument to `div2` is a function, not something you can divide by 2. Your decorator should be

```
def div2(f):
    def display(x):
        print(f"We are doing a check of multiples if div by 2")
        if f(x) % 2 == 0:
            return f"{x} is divisible"
    return display

@div2
def multi(n):
    return n*n*n

prin(multi(5))
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Here multi takes one parameter, named `n`.

```
def multi(n):
    return n*n*n
```

And using the decorator syntax is actually the same as doing:

```
multi = div2(multi)
```

Thus if you want be able to pass paramaters to the wrapper `display` it has to be defined to take the parameters.